# Fix javascript sticky header jump when using css transition

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following sticky header that appears when you scroll down the page past 100px.

```js
var scrollpos = window.scrollY;
var header = document.getElementById("masthead");

function add_class_on_scroll() {
    header.classList.add("slide-in");
}

function remove_class_on_scroll() {
    header.classList.remove("slide-in");
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){ 
    scrollpos = window.scrollY;
    if(scrollpos > 188) {
        add_class_on_scroll();
    }
    else {
        remove_class_on_scroll();
    }
});
```

```css
html {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.site {
  position: relative;
}

.site-header {
 position: relative;
  top: -100px;
  height: 100px;
 background-color: #f5f5f5;
 transition: top ease-in-out 1s;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.slide-in {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="site">

  <header id="masthead" class="site-header">
    <p>I'm the site header</p>
  </header>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce consectetur diam dui. Curabitur egestas augue non arcu tincidunt, ut fermentum mi lacinia. Sed vehicula non lectus at efficitur. Sed bibendum ipsum sed cursus condimentum. Maecenas non leo semper nisl consequat vestibulum. Maecenas vestibulum sodales metus, in varius ante efficitur a. Integer ipsum orci, ultrices facilisis mi sed, bibendum egestas ipsum. Maecenas nec elit non libero bibendum condimentum.</p>

  <p>Suspendisse potenti. Vestibulum vestibulum, diam eleifend mattis dictum, ante nulla semper est, at fermentum leo ligula sit amet nunc. Nullam gravida sem et urna maximus, eu efficitur eros hendrerit. Aliquam convallis facilisis mi sed congue. Praesent pulvinar vehicula urna, quis iaculis nisi vestibulum non. Aliquam pulvinar risus id blandit malesuada. Proin pharetra, nibh nec consequat fringilla, erat quam sollicitudin orci, id tincidunt ex justo in diam. Vestibulum eleifend metus urna, at interdum arcu venenatis ac. Nam euismod, lorem ac fringilla bibendum, dui massa volutpat nulla, non aliquam nisi ligula id ligula. Sed iaculis viverra nisi eget mattis.</p>

  <p>Phasellus ac lacus tincidunt, vestibulum dolor eget, dictum massa. Fusce fringilla lorem sed ex placerat ornare. Aenean in consequat mauris, in dapibus enim. Sed commodo posuere est ut lobortis. Nulla elementum pretium ante eu elementum. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur quam velit, varius nec leo vitae, scelerisque dignissim justo.</p>

  <p>Donec nec rutrum tortor, ac semper dolor. Maecenas id laoreet orci. Vivamus tincidunt commodo nisi sit amet posuere. Vestibulum pretium risus ante, non mattis ex eleifend quis. Ut id scelerisque tortor, quis ullamcorper orci. Sed vestibulum pharetra nibh. Donec ultricies nibh neque, vitae ullamcorper elit rhoncus a. Nunc odio turpis, euismod at tempus vitae, aliquet in lectus. Praesent vehicula lectus et enim fringilla feugiat.</p>

  <p>Quisque eleifend libero a mi sodales vehicula. Aliquam erat volutpat. Maecenas dignissim rutrum auctor. Vestibulum pretium lacus quis vehicula placerat. Cras placerat leo non libero imperdiet, ac tristique ligula feugiat. Aliquam semper aliquam ligula, sed fermentum erat sagittis eget. Donec lorem urna, tristique at suscipit sed, euismod nec odio.</p>

  <p>Aliquam lobortis lorem non libero varius, in ultricies ipsum ornare. Sed imperdiet elementum ligula, non blandit nunc imperdiet quis. Vivamus ut dictum est, quis euismod orci. Sed eget magna ac massa gravida porta. Donec nibh massa, scelerisque ac tempus a, fringilla vel nunc. Aenean malesuada pulvinar quam sed pretium. Aenean id dui a neque lobortis dictum vitae ac ipsum. Donec interdum ligula mattis enim facilisis vehicula facilisis id eros. Donec eu dolor sit amet neque ultricies faucibus nec et arcu. Proin vulputate elementum dui nec gravida. Nunc odio justo, consequat non tortor ut, rutrum mollis magna. Donec ac leo elit. Fusce hendrerit maximus est mattis porta. Praesent malesuada interdum orci nec viverra. Mauris porta ligula in auctor tincidunt. Suspendisse potenti.</p>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse aliquet purus quis enim egestas tincidunt. Maecenas mattis ut metus eget viverra. Praesent hendrerit odio tincidunt, feugiat metus quis, gravida turpis. Aenean sed mauris commodo libero placerat malesuada eu accumsan lacus. Mauris mi tortor, fringilla nec velit tristique, eleifend pulvinar nunc. Integer nec accumsan mauris. Maecenas mattis, est sit amet congue consectetur, mi massa dignissim urna, ut efficitur orci est et ex. In ac lorem viverra, dictum libero at, pellentesque neque. Cras congue volutpat diam ac luctus. Etiam iaculis augue enim, eget pharetra ligula posuere ac.</p>

  <p>Curabitur elementum malesuada nulla, nec semper lectus pretium eget. Proin tempor tortor sed lectus sollicitudin bibendum. Donec non sodales nibh. Suspendisse gravida, purus eget fringilla sagittis, quam ex tempus nisl, quis consectetur orci elit in nisi. Nam tincidunt finibus leo sed consectetur. Etiam sit amet ex aliquet, varius augue ac, consequat nisl. Integer ac dignissim lacus. Ut at facilisis ligula, vel viverra mauris. Phasellus ut egestas turpis. Phasellus sit amet quam ut dui hendrerit tincidunt eget et nisi. Donec tempor dapibus enim. Etiam eget nunc eleifend, hendrerit diam vitae, fringilla mi. Nunc a condimentum felis.</p>

  <p>Vestibulum pharetra ultricies ultrices. Vestibulum cursus ante felis. Sed aliquet, elit eget posuere consequat, mauris arcu tincidunt dolor, at porta erat orci a felis. In quis viverra diam. Vestibulum porta nisi purus, lacinia placerat ligula posuere et. Ut aliquet commodo sem non luctus. Mauris suscipit justo eget turpis interdum blandit eu eu purus. Integer condimentum blandit sapien id pellentesque. In convallis odio in neque accumsan, vitae volutpat mi ornare. Vivamus a augue quis tellus facilisis luctus. Integer laoreet, tortor vel interdum blandit, arcu arcu ornare nunc, in cursus mi tellus vitae mauris. Etiam molestie nibh sapien, id auctor nulla ullamcorper in. Maecenas vel justo est. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Pellentesque porttitor lacinia ipsum ultricies rutrum.</p>

  <p>Quisque varius tempor tellus. Morbi eleifend venenatis nunc, sed sodales tortor vulputate a. Quisque non risus ut nunc viverra suscipit non rhoncus neque. Aliquam at efficitur ligula. Ut diam tortor, feugiat ut rutrum ac, imperdiet in nibh. Proin at odio nec mi aliquet efficitur lobortis vitae turpis. Curabitur molestie odio nec laoreet luctus. Praesent vel ligula at felis convallis accumsan. Fusce cursus nisi orci, in placerat lorem congue convallis. Praesent pellentesque consequat elit, nec interdum velit tincidunt a.</p>

  <p>Nullam efficitur est ligula, non fringilla massa pulvinar at. Aliquam non porta tortor. Aenean sit amet mollis turpis. Curabitur convallis sollicitudin leo a aliquam. Praesent vitae semper odio. Curabitur condimentum lorem eget dapibus volutpat. Vivamus id tortor erat. Cras mollis varius dolor. Donec laoreet, ipsum sed sollicitudin placerat, nulla diam consequat nibh, sit amet lobortis diam turpis vitae dui. Aliquam dapibus diam nec porttitor egestas. Nam eu tristique orci, in tristique tortor. Sed est ex, scelerisque sed ligula a, condimentum maximus augue. Phasellus malesuada augue libero, eu consectetur magna rhoncus a. Sed ipsum tellus, viverra ut suscipit id, efficitur eu est.</p>

  <p>Proin sagittis magna ac enim varius maximus. Quisque vel neque tincidunt, malesuada diam ut, bibendum tortor. Praesent feugiat ante egestas, convallis nisi at, ornare lacus. Nunc non sem vel orci posuere efficitur. Morbi accumsan ipsum ut turpis rhoncus, id ultricies nulla mollis. Sed purus diam, pellentesque vitae quam ac, hendrerit suscipit eros. Quisque euismod, nunc sit amet varius fermentum, sapien purus condimentum nunc, sit amet ultricies lacus turpis eu ante. Donec pulvinar iaculis blandit. Morbi quis ligula lorem. In in bibendum libero. Integer convallis elit eu ex lobortis, nec luctus libero ultrices. Nam ullamcorper posuere cursus. Ut feugiat, mauris scelerisque facilisis eleifend, magna massa maximus mi, at porttitor ex leo sit amet nisl. Praesent ligula purus, aliquet in commodo sit amet, porttitor ac velit. Nunc sodales elementum arcu, et fringilla libero ultricies ut. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae;</p>

  <p>Ut nec interdum magna. Aenean sit amet vehicula neque. Nunc tincidunt ultrices tellus vitae pretium. Pellentesque posuere ultricies diam, ullamcorper hendrerit nibh ullamcorper in. Maecenas ut est et elit venenatis vestibulum. Vestibulum id hendrerit eros. Aliquam efficitur est elit, nec malesuada purus posuere ac. Morbi eu est porttitor, condimentum arcu eget, pretium nisi. Aliquam viverra enim vitae vulputate viverra. Nullam vitae metus sodales, finibus justo vel, efficitur neque. Morbi euismod rutrum tempus. Donec cursus lectus sed commodo vestibulum. Vivamus eu ligula consequat, cursus neque ac, tempus sapien.</p>

  <p>Donec vel urna ac lacus consectetur cursus. Donec tempor justo ornare libero eleifend, id ultrices nisi tincidunt. Donec ac orci eget ligula auctor pretium sit amet eu purus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nunc ac luctus elit. Sed consectetur, elit at consequat mollis, justo lectus pellentesque lectus, malesuada congue erat velit eu tortor. Donec ullamcorper nibh a dui convallis venenatis. In a ullamcorper nulla, id porttitor nunc. Praesent elit orci, aliquam vel nunc sed, scelerisque tincidunt ex. Duis consequat dignissim lacus, id porttitor libero fringilla quis. Fusce libero dolor, consectetur id pharetra at, tristique eget sem. Donec et mollis nunc, in aliquet ligula.</p>

  <p>Cras pellentesque imperdiet laoreet. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque ultrices aliquet pretium. Integer auctor sem magna, eget condimentum sapien elementum ac. Nunc finibus feugiat aliquet. Quisque libero ligula, congue sit amet vestibulum at, euismod a elit. Vivamus eget augue et nunc lobortis hendrerit sed ut turpis. Donec et ante commodo, faucibus felis in, viverra libero. Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis euismod magna eget metus tincidunt dapibus. Curabitur malesuada efficitur venenatis. Fusce eu nisi sed purus hendrerit consectetur et ac tellus. Cras placerat dignissim mauris, egestas bibendum eros pulvinar non. Quisque finibus eget elit eu placerat. Mauris diam metus, imperdiet et libero sit amet, venenatis finibus libero. Cras eget laoreet justo.</p>

  <p>Proin sit amet orci nec magna tincidunt vehicula. Praesent mauris elit, ullamcorper eget odio sed, pulvinar luctus tellus. Mauris tempus, magna tempus vulputate efficitur, elit lectus accumsan est, ultricies volutpat nulla ante in sapien. Morbi condimentum erat sit amet mattis ullamcorper. Nullam tincidunt nunc vel leo vulputate porttitor. Donec efficitur hendrerit nunc, non viverra libero scelerisque ac. Ut gravida nec ante vitae facilisis. Pellentesque sagittis urna sit amet egestas vestibulum.</p>

  <p>Duis tempus dui in interdum ullamcorper. Curabitur vulputate laoreet est, dictum condimentum sapien vehicula eget. Pellentesque ac dictum mi. Sed metus arcu, sodales lobortis urna vel, feugiat ullamcorper est. Integer lacinia, lacus ac tristique convallis, nunc purus bibendum arcu, at eleifend enim est non ipsum. Nam iaculis elementum convallis. Nulla tempus odio vel porta ullamcorper. Donec dignissim ut elit vestibulum faucibus.</p>

  <p>Aenean a pulvinar ante. Nunc rutrum volutpat tincidunt. Aenean ultricies sodales mauris eget suscipit. Proin rhoncus ornare lacus in auctor. Duis nec urna sit amet tortor ullamcorper sagittis non nec massa. Nullam dolor sem, laoreet sit amet elit in, iaculis consequat turpis. Morbi semper nulla vel egestas ultrices. Suspendisse id est iaculis, facilisis metus non, accumsan augue. Vestibulum arcu nulla, porta euismod felis et, sollicitudin vehicula ligula. Pellentesque ac dolor ac eros gravida tempus. Etiam sed sem ultrices, tincidunt purus eget, porttitor eros. Vivamus ut tempor sem. Donec interdum efficitur mollis.</p>

  <p>In a laoreet ante. Suspendisse potenti. In sit amet enim elit. In arcu mauris, luctus a urna eget, aliquet accumsan tellus. Maecenas egestas, sem nec commodo tincidunt, metus tortor volutpat libero, eget tristique metus velit sed eros. Fusce bibendum lacus id lectus semper, id volutpat turpis dictum. Vestibulum eu elit eget eros dictum cursus. Mauris consectetur dolor eu ligula condimentum aliquam at id dui. Vestibulum non dolor ante. Morbi a dapibus erat. Nulla placerat mi id neque rhoncus, et semper dolor hendrerit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas quam sem, dapibus non aliquet iaculis, mollis id urna.</p>

  <p>Integer pellentesque enim a justo venenatis sodales. Etiam in nisl ipsum. Vestibulum fringilla dignissim faucibus. Nam pellentesque, mi ac accumsan mattis, elit velit bibendum lacus, id scelerisque ligula sapien id diam. Sed condimentum rutrum metus, in sollicitudin quam ultricies ut. Phasellus at lobortis arcu. Duis auctor, arcu id hendrerit faucibus, odio turpis finibus mi, molestie tempus ex lorem suscipit enim. Nam pretium laoreet ipsum. Donec eu mauris euismod, varius mi id, elementum leo. Integer ultricies nulla massa, in consequat lectus pellentesque ut. Ut eu risus mi. Pellentesque id ligula sodales, maximus lorem at, bibendum velit. Etiam vitae eros vitae quam lacinia egestas. Sed ullamcorper egestas magna, eget suscipit nulla euismod a. Morbi accumsan arcu a vulputate iaculis.</p>

</div>
```

The problem I'm having is when I scroll back up and the `.slide-in` class is removed, the header snaps back into position without a transition. This looks a little buggy.

I've used `transition: top ease-in-out 1s;` on `.site-header` but this doesn't have an effect when the class is removed. Is there a way to apply a transition in reverse for when the class is removed?

I'm using `position: relative;` instead of fixed `position: fixed;` because I want the header to be hidden when you're at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is because you used position `relative` & `sticky` in two different situation.

- **relative** is related to it's parent div
- **static** is related to it's screen

```js
var scrollpos = window.scrollY;
var header = document.getElementById("masthead");

function add_class_on_scroll() {
    header.classList.add("slide-in");
}

function remove_class_on_scroll() {
    header.classList.remove("slide-in");
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){ 
    scrollpos = window.scrollY;
    if(scrollpos > 188) {
        add_class_on_scroll();
    }
    else {
        remove_class_on_scroll();
    }
});
```

```css
html {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.site {
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.site-header {
 position: fixed;
  height: 100px;
  top: -100px;
 background-color: #f5f5f5;
 transition: top ease-in-out 1s;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  Width:100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide-in {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="site">

  <header id="masthead" class="site-header">
    <p>I'm the site header</p>
  </header>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce consectetur diam dui. Curabitur egestas augue non arcu tincidunt, ut fermentum mi lacinia. Sed vehicula non lectus at efficitur. Sed bibendum ipsum sed cursus condimentum. Maecenas non leo semper nisl consequat vestibulum. Maecenas vestibulum sodales metus, in varius ante efficitur a. Integer ipsum orci, ultrices facilisis mi sed, bibendum egestas ipsum. Maecenas nec elit non libero bibendum condimentum.</p>

  <p>Suspendisse potenti. Vestibulum vestibulum, diam eleifend mattis dictum, ante nulla semper est, at fermentum leo ligula sit amet nunc. Nullam gravida sem et urna maximus, eu efficitur eros hendrerit. Aliquam convallis facilisis mi sed congue. Praesent pulvinar vehicula urna, quis iaculis nisi vestibulum non. Aliquam pulvinar risus id blandit malesuada. Proin pharetra, nibh nec consequat fringilla, erat quam sollicitudin orci, id tincidunt ex justo in diam. Vestibulum eleifend metus urna, at interdum arcu venenatis ac. Nam euismod, lorem ac fringilla bibendum, dui massa volutpat nulla, non aliquam nisi ligula id ligula. Sed iaculis viverra nisi eget mattis.</p>

  <p>Phasellus ac lacus tincidunt, vestibulum dolor eget, dictum massa. Fusce fringilla lorem sed ex placerat ornare. Aenean in consequat mauris, in dapibus enim. Sed commodo posuere est ut lobortis. Nulla elementum pretium ante eu elementum. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur quam velit, varius nec leo vitae, scelerisque dignissim justo.</p>

  <p>Donec nec rutrum tortor, ac semper dolor. Maecenas id laoreet orci. Vivamus tincidunt commodo nisi sit amet posuere. Vestibulum pretium risus ante, non mattis ex eleifend quis. Ut id scelerisque tortor, quis ullamcorper orci. Sed vestibulum pharetra nibh. Donec ultricies nibh neque, vitae ullamcorper elit rhoncus a. Nunc odio turpis, euismod at tempus vitae, aliquet in lectus. Praesent vehicula lectus et enim fringilla feugiat.</p>

  <p>Quisque eleifend libero a mi sodales vehicula. Aliquam erat volutpat. Maecenas dignissim rutrum auctor. Vestibulum pretium lacus quis vehicula placerat. Cras placerat leo non libero imperdiet, ac tristique ligula feugiat. Aliquam semper aliquam ligula, sed fermentum erat sagittis eget. Donec lorem urna, tristique at suscipit sed, euismod nec odio.</p>

  <p>Aliquam lobortis lorem non libero varius, in ultricies ipsum ornare. Sed imperdiet elementum ligula, non blandit nunc imperdiet quis. Vivamus ut dictum est, quis euismod orci. Sed eget magna ac massa gravida porta. Donec nibh massa, scelerisque ac tempus a, fringilla vel nunc. Aenean malesuada pulvinar quam sed pretium. Aenean id dui a neque lobortis dictum vitae ac ipsum. Donec interdum ligula mattis enim facilisis vehicula facilisis id eros. Donec eu dolor sit amet neque ultricies faucibus nec et arcu. Proin vulputate elementum dui nec gravida. Nunc odio justo, consequat non tortor ut, rutrum mollis magna. Donec ac leo elit. Fusce hendrerit maximus est mattis porta. Praesent malesuada interdum orci nec viverra. Mauris porta ligula in auctor tincidunt. Suspendisse potenti.</p>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse aliquet purus quis enim egestas tincidunt. Maecenas mattis ut metus eget viverra. Praesent hendrerit odio tincidunt, feugiat metus quis, gravida turpis. Aenean sed mauris commodo libero placerat malesuada eu accumsan lacus. Mauris mi tortor, fringilla nec velit tristique, eleifend pulvinar nunc. Integer nec accumsan mauris. Maecenas mattis, est sit amet congue consectetur, mi massa dignissim urna, ut efficitur orci est et ex. In ac lorem viverra, dictum libero at, pellentesque neque. Cras congue volutpat diam ac luctus. Etiam iaculis augue enim, eget pharetra ligula posuere ac.</p>

  <p>Curabitur elementum malesuada nulla, nec semper lectus pretium eget. Proin tempor tortor sed lectus sollicitudin bibendum. Donec non sodales nibh. Suspendisse gravida, purus eget fringilla sagittis, quam ex tempus nisl, quis consectetur orci elit in nisi. Nam tincidunt finibus leo sed consectetur. Etiam sit amet ex aliquet, varius augue ac, consequat nisl. Integer ac dignissim lacus. Ut at facilisis ligula, vel viverra mauris. Phasellus ut egestas turpis. Phasellus sit amet quam ut dui hendrerit tincidunt eget et nisi. Donec tempor dapibus enim. Etiam eget nunc eleifend, hendrerit diam vitae, fringilla mi. Nunc a condimentum felis.</p>

  <p>Vestibulum pharetra ultricies ultrices. Vestibulum cursus ante felis. Sed aliquet, elit eget posuere consequat, mauris arcu tincidunt dolor, at porta erat orci a felis. In quis viverra diam. Vestibulum porta nisi purus, lacinia placerat ligula posuere et. Ut aliquet commodo sem non luctus. Mauris suscipit justo eget turpis interdum blandit eu eu purus. Integer condimentum blandit sapien id pellentesque. In convallis odio in neque accumsan, vitae volutpat mi ornare. Vivamus a augue quis tellus facilisis luctus. Integer laoreet, tortor vel interdum blandit, arcu arcu ornare nunc, in cursus mi tellus vitae mauris. Etiam molestie nibh sapien, id auctor nulla ullamcorper in. Maecenas vel justo est. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Pellentesque porttitor lacinia ipsum ultricies rutrum.</p>

  <p>Quisque varius tempor tellus. Morbi eleifend venenatis nunc, sed sodales tortor vulputate a. Quisque non risus ut nunc viverra suscipit non rhoncus neque. Aliquam at efficitur ligula. Ut diam tortor, feugiat ut rutrum ac, imperdiet in nibh. Proin at odio nec mi aliquet efficitur lobortis vitae turpis. Curabitur molestie odio nec laoreet luctus. Praesent vel ligula at felis convallis accumsan. Fusce cursus nisi orci, in placerat lorem congue convallis. Praesent pellentesque consequat elit, nec interdum velit tincidunt a.</p>

  <p>Nullam efficitur est ligula, non fringilla massa pulvinar at. Aliquam non porta tortor. Aenean sit amet mollis turpis. Curabitur convallis sollicitudin leo a aliquam. Praesent vitae semper odio. Curabitur condimentum lorem eget dapibus volutpat. Vivamus id tortor erat. Cras mollis varius dolor. Donec laoreet, ipsum sed sollicitudin placerat, nulla diam consequat nibh, sit amet lobortis diam turpis vitae dui. Aliquam dapibus diam nec porttitor egestas. Nam eu tristique orci, in tristique tortor. Sed est ex, scelerisque sed ligula a, condimentum maximus augue. Phasellus malesuada augue libero, eu consectetur magna rhoncus a. Sed ipsum tellus, viverra ut suscipit id, efficitur eu est.</p>

  <p>Proin sagittis magna ac enim varius maximus. Quisque vel neque tincidunt, malesuada diam ut, bibendum tortor. Praesent feugiat ante egestas, convallis nisi at, ornare lacus. Nunc non sem vel orci posuere efficitur. Morbi accumsan ipsum ut turpis rhoncus, id ultricies nulla mollis. Sed purus diam, pellentesque vitae quam ac, hendrerit suscipit eros. Quisque euismod, nunc sit amet varius fermentum, sapien purus condimentum nunc, sit amet ultricies lacus turpis eu ante. Donec pulvinar iaculis blandit. Morbi quis ligula lorem. In in bibendum libero. Integer convallis elit eu ex lobortis, nec luctus libero ultrices. Nam ullamcorper posuere cursus. Ut feugiat, mauris scelerisque facilisis eleifend, magna massa maximus mi, at porttitor ex leo sit amet nisl. Praesent ligula purus, aliquet in commodo sit amet, porttitor ac velit. Nunc sodales elementum arcu, et fringilla libero ultricies ut. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae;</p>

  <p>Ut nec interdum magna. Aenean sit amet vehicula neque. Nunc tincidunt ultrices tellus vitae pretium. Pellentesque posuere ultricies diam, ullamcorper hendrerit nibh ullamcorper in. Maecenas ut est et elit venenatis vestibulum. Vestibulum id hendrerit eros. Aliquam efficitur est elit, nec malesuada purus posuere ac. Morbi eu est porttitor, condimentum arcu eget, pretium nisi. Aliquam viverra enim vitae vulputate viverra. Nullam vitae metus sodales, finibus justo vel, efficitur neque. Morbi euismod rutrum tempus. Donec cursus lectus sed commodo vestibulum. Vivamus eu ligula consequat, cursus neque ac, tempus sapien.</p>

  <p>Donec vel urna ac lacus consectetur cursus. Donec tempor justo ornare libero eleifend, id ultrices nisi tincidunt. Donec ac orci eget ligula auctor pretium sit amet eu purus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nunc ac luctus elit. Sed consectetur, elit at consequat mollis, justo lectus pellentesque lectus, malesuada congue erat velit eu tortor. Donec ullamcorper nibh a dui convallis venenatis. In a ullamcorper nulla, id porttitor nunc. Praesent elit orci, aliquam vel nunc sed, scelerisque tincidunt ex. Duis consequat dignissim lacus, id porttitor libero fringilla quis. Fusce libero dolor, consectetur id pharetra at, tristique eget sem. Donec et mollis nunc, in aliquet ligula.</p>

  <p>Cras pellentesque imperdiet laoreet. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque ultrices aliquet pretium. Integer auctor sem magna, eget condimentum sapien elementum ac. Nunc finibus feugiat aliquet. Quisque libero ligula, congue sit amet vestibulum at, euismod a elit. Vivamus eget augue et nunc lobortis hendrerit sed ut turpis. Donec et ante commodo, faucibus felis in, viverra libero. Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis euismod magna eget metus tincidunt dapibus. Curabitur malesuada efficitur venenatis. Fusce eu nisi sed purus hendrerit consectetur et ac tellus. Cras placerat dignissim mauris, egestas bibendum eros pulvinar non. Quisque finibus eget elit eu placerat. Mauris diam metus, imperdiet et libero sit amet, venenatis finibus libero. Cras eget laoreet justo.</p>

  <p>Proin sit amet orci nec magna tincidunt vehicula. Praesent mauris elit, ullamcorper eget odio sed, pulvinar luctus tellus. Mauris tempus, magna tempus vulputate efficitur, elit lectus accumsan est, ultricies volutpat nulla ante in sapien. Morbi condimentum erat sit amet mattis ullamcorper. Nullam tincidunt nunc vel leo vulputate porttitor. Donec efficitur hendrerit nunc, non viverra libero scelerisque ac. Ut gravida nec ante vitae facilisis. Pellentesque sagittis urna sit amet egestas vestibulum.</p>

  <p>Duis tempus dui in interdum ullamcorper. Curabitur vulputate laoreet est, dictum condimentum sapien vehicula eget. Pellentesque ac dictum mi. Sed metus arcu, sodales lobortis urna vel, feugiat ullamcorper est. Integer lacinia, lacus ac tristique convallis, nunc purus bibendum arcu, at eleifend enim est non ipsum. Nam iaculis elementum convallis. Nulla tempus odio vel porta ullamcorper. Donec dignissim ut elit vestibulum faucibus.</p>

  <p>Aenean a pulvinar ante. Nunc rutrum volutpat tincidunt. Aenean ultricies sodales mauris eget suscipit. Proin rhoncus ornare lacus in auctor. Duis nec urna sit amet tortor ullamcorper sagittis non nec massa. Nullam dolor sem, laoreet sit amet elit in, iaculis consequat turpis. Morbi semper nulla vel egestas ultrices. Suspendisse id est iaculis, facilisis metus non, accumsan augue. Vestibulum arcu nulla, porta euismod felis et, sollicitudin vehicula ligula. Pellentesque ac dolor ac eros gravida tempus. Etiam sed sem ultrices, tincidunt purus eget, porttitor eros. Vivamus ut tempor sem. Donec interdum efficitur mollis.</p>

  <p>In a laoreet ante. Suspendisse potenti. In sit amet enim elit. In arcu mauris, luctus a urna eget, aliquet accumsan tellus. Maecenas egestas, sem nec commodo tincidunt, metus tortor volutpat libero, eget tristique metus velit sed eros. Fusce bibendum lacus id lectus semper, id volutpat turpis dictum. Vestibulum eu elit eget eros dictum cursus. Mauris consectetur dolor eu ligula condimentum aliquam at id dui. Vestibulum non dolor ante. Morbi a dapibus erat. Nulla placerat mi id neque rhoncus, et semper dolor hendrerit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas quam sem, dapibus non aliquet iaculis, mollis id urna.</p>

  <p>Integer pellentesque enim a justo venenatis sodales. Etiam in nisl ipsum. Vestibulum fringilla dignissim faucibus. Nam pellentesque, mi ac accumsan mattis, elit velit bibendum lacus, id scelerisque ligula sapien id diam. Sed condimentum rutrum metus, in sollicitudin quam ultricies ut. Phasellus at lobortis arcu. Duis auctor, arcu id hendrerit faucibus, odio turpis finibus mi, molestie tempus ex lorem suscipit enim. Nam pretium laoreet ipsum. Donec eu mauris euismod, varius mi id, elementum leo. Integer ultricies nulla massa, in consequat lectus pellentesque ut. Ut eu risus mi. Pellentesque id ligula sodales, maximus lorem at, bibendum velit. Etiam vitae eros vitae quam lacinia egestas. Sed ullamcorper egestas magna, eget suscipit nulla euismod a. Morbi accumsan arcu a vulputate iaculis.</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is due to a position change, you are having its one position to another and that is causing this issue. Try to have same position, either sticky or fixed.

```js
var scrollpos = window.scrollY;
var header = document.getElementById("masthead");

function add_class_on_scroll() {
    header.classList.add("slide-in");
}

function remove_class_on_scroll() {
    header.classList.remove("slide-in");
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){ 
    scrollpos = window.scrollY;
    if(scrollpos > 188) {
        add_class_on_scroll();
    }
    else {
        remove_class_on_scroll();
    }
});
```

```css
html {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.site {
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.site-header {
 position: fixed;
  top: -100px;
  height: 0;
 background-color: #f5f5f5;
 transition: all ease-in-out 1s;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
Width:100%;
left: 0;
}

.slide-in {
  position: fixed;
  height:100px;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="site">

  <header id="masthead" class="site-header">
    <p>I'm the site header</p>
  </header>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce consectetur diam dui. Curabitur egestas augue non arcu tincidunt, ut fermentum mi lacinia. Sed vehicula non lectus at efficitur. Sed bibendum ipsum sed cursus condimentum. Maecenas non leo semper nisl consequat vestibulum. Maecenas vestibulum sodales metus, in varius ante efficitur a. Integer ipsum orci, ultrices facilisis mi sed, bibendum egestas ipsum. Maecenas nec elit non libero bibendum condimentum.</p>

  <p>Suspendisse potenti. Vestibulum vestibulum, diam eleifend mattis dictum, ante nulla semper est, at fermentum leo ligula sit amet nunc. Nullam gravida sem et urna maximus, eu efficitur eros hendrerit. Aliquam convallis facilisis mi sed congue. Praesent pulvinar vehicula urna, quis iaculis nisi vestibulum non. Aliquam pulvinar risus id blandit malesuada. Proin pharetra, nibh nec consequat fringilla, erat quam sollicitudin orci, id tincidunt ex justo in diam. Vestibulum eleifend metus urna, at interdum arcu venenatis ac. Nam euismod, lorem ac fringilla bibendum, dui massa volutpat nulla, non aliquam nisi ligula id ligula. Sed iaculis viverra nisi eget mattis.</p>

  <p>Phasellus ac lacus tincidunt, vestibulum dolor eget, dictum massa. Fusce fringilla lorem sed ex placerat ornare. Aenean in consequat mauris, in dapibus enim. Sed commodo posuere est ut lobortis. Nulla elementum pretium ante eu elementum. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur quam velit, varius nec leo vitae, scelerisque dignissim justo.</p>

  <p>Donec nec rutrum tortor, ac semper dolor. Maecenas id laoreet orci. Vivamus tincidunt commodo nisi sit amet posuere. Vestibulum pretium risus ante, non mattis ex eleifend quis. Ut id scelerisque tortor, quis ullamcorper orci. Sed vestibulum pharetra nibh. Donec ultricies nibh neque, vitae ullamcorper elit rhoncus a. Nunc odio turpis, euismod at tempus vitae, aliquet in lectus. Praesent vehicula lectus et enim fringilla feugiat.</p>

  <p>Quisque eleifend libero a mi sodales vehicula. Aliquam erat volutpat. Maecenas dignissim rutrum auctor. Vestibulum pretium lacus quis vehicula placerat. Cras placerat leo non libero imperdiet, ac tristique ligula feugiat. Aliquam semper aliquam ligula, sed fermentum erat sagittis eget. Donec lorem urna, tristique at suscipit sed, euismod nec odio.</p>

  <p>Aliquam lobortis lorem non libero varius, in ultricies ipsum ornare. Sed imperdiet elementum ligula, non blandit nunc imperdiet quis. Vivamus ut dictum est, quis euismod orci. Sed eget magna ac massa gravida porta. Donec nibh massa, scelerisque ac tempus a, fringilla vel nunc. Aenean malesuada pulvinar quam sed pretium. Aenean id dui a neque lobortis dictum vitae ac ipsum. Donec interdum ligula mattis enim facilisis vehicula facilisis id eros. Donec eu dolor sit amet neque ultricies faucibus nec et arcu. Proin vulputate elementum dui nec gravida. Nunc odio justo, consequat non tortor ut, rutrum mollis magna. Donec ac leo elit. Fusce hendrerit maximus est mattis porta. Praesent malesuada interdum orci nec viverra. Mauris porta ligula in auctor tincidunt. Suspendisse potenti.</p>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse aliquet purus quis enim egestas tincidunt. Maecenas mattis ut metus eget viverra. Praesent hendrerit odio tincidunt, feugiat metus quis, gravida turpis. Aenean sed mauris commodo libero placerat malesuada eu accumsan lacus. Mauris mi tortor, fringilla nec velit tristique, eleifend pulvinar nunc. Integer nec accumsan mauris. Maecenas mattis, est sit amet congue consectetur, mi massa dignissim urna, ut efficitur orci est et ex. In ac lorem viverra, dictum libero at, pellentesque neque. Cras congue volutpat diam ac luctus. Etiam iaculis augue enim, eget pharetra ligula posuere ac.</p>

  <p>Curabitur elementum malesuada nulla, nec semper lectus pretium eget. Proin tempor tortor sed lectus sollicitudin bibendum. Donec non sodales nibh. Suspendisse gravida, purus eget fringilla sagittis, quam ex tempus nisl, quis consectetur orci elit in nisi. Nam tincidunt finibus leo sed consectetur. Etiam sit amet ex aliquet, varius augue ac, consequat nisl. Integer ac dignissim lacus. Ut at facilisis ligula, vel viverra mauris. Phasellus ut egestas turpis. Phasellus sit amet quam ut dui hendrerit tincidunt eget et nisi. Donec tempor dapibus enim. Etiam eget nunc eleifend, hendrerit diam vitae, fringilla mi. Nunc a condimentum felis.</p>

  <p>Vestibulum pharetra ultricies ultrices. Vestibulum cursus ante felis. Sed aliquet, elit eget posuere consequat, mauris arcu tincidunt dolor, at porta erat orci a felis. In quis viverra diam. Vestibulum porta nisi purus, lacinia placerat ligula posuere et. Ut aliquet commodo sem non luctus. Mauris suscipit justo eget turpis interdum blandit eu eu purus. Integer condimentum blandit sapien id pellentesque. In convallis odio in neque accumsan, vitae volutpat mi ornare. Vivamus a augue quis tellus facilisis luctus. Integer laoreet, tortor vel interdum blandit, arcu arcu ornare nunc, in cursus mi tellus vitae mauris. Etiam molestie nibh sapien, id auctor nulla ullamcorper in. Maecenas vel justo est. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Pellentesque porttitor lacinia ipsum ultricies rutrum.</p>

  <p>Quisque varius tempor tellus. Morbi eleifend venenatis nunc, sed sodales tortor vulputate a. Quisque non risus ut nunc viverra suscipit non rhoncus neque. Aliquam at efficitur ligula. Ut diam tortor, feugiat ut rutrum ac, imperdiet in nibh. Proin at odio nec mi aliquet efficitur lobortis vitae turpis. Curabitur molestie odio nec laoreet luctus. Praesent vel ligula at felis convallis accumsan. Fusce cursus nisi orci, in placerat lorem congue convallis. Praesent pellentesque consequat elit, nec interdum velit tincidunt a.</p>

  <p>Nullam efficitur est ligula, non fringilla massa pulvinar at. Aliquam non porta tortor. Aenean sit amet mollis turpis. Curabitur convallis sollicitudin leo a aliquam. Praesent vitae semper odio. Curabitur condimentum lorem eget dapibus volutpat. Vivamus id tortor erat. Cras mollis varius dolor. Donec laoreet, ipsum sed sollicitudin placerat, nulla diam consequat nibh, sit amet lobortis diam turpis vitae dui. Aliquam dapibus diam nec porttitor egestas. Nam eu tristique orci, in tristique tortor. Sed est ex, scelerisque sed ligula a, condimentum maximus augue. Phasellus malesuada augue libero, eu consectetur magna rhoncus a. Sed ipsum tellus, viverra ut suscipit id, efficitur eu est.</p>

  <p>Proin sagittis magna ac enim varius maximus. Quisque vel neque tincidunt, malesuada diam ut, bibendum tortor. Praesent feugiat ante egestas, convallis nisi at, ornare lacus. Nunc non sem vel orci posuere efficitur. Morbi accumsan ipsum ut turpis rhoncus, id ultricies nulla mollis. Sed purus diam, pellentesque vitae quam ac, hendrerit suscipit eros. Quisque euismod, nunc sit amet varius fermentum, sapien purus condimentum nunc, sit amet ultricies lacus turpis eu ante. Donec pulvinar iaculis blandit. Morbi quis ligula lorem. In in bibendum libero. Integer convallis elit eu ex lobortis, nec luctus libero ultrices. Nam ullamcorper posuere cursus. Ut feugiat, mauris scelerisque facilisis eleifend, magna massa maximus mi, at porttitor ex leo sit amet nisl. Praesent ligula purus, aliquet in commodo sit amet, porttitor ac velit. Nunc sodales elementum arcu, et fringilla libero ultricies ut. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae;</p>

  <p>Ut nec interdum magna. Aenean sit amet vehicula neque. Nunc tincidunt ultrices tellus vitae pretium. Pellentesque posuere ultricies diam, ullamcorper hendrerit nibh ullamcorper in. Maecenas ut est et elit venenatis vestibulum. Vestibulum id hendrerit eros. Aliquam efficitur est elit, nec malesuada purus posuere ac. Morbi eu est porttitor, condimentum arcu eget, pretium nisi. Aliquam viverra enim vitae vulputate viverra. Nullam vitae metus sodales, finibus justo vel, efficitur neque. Morbi euismod rutrum tempus. Donec cursus lectus sed commodo vestibulum. Vivamus eu ligula consequat, cursus neque ac, tempus sapien.</p>

  <p>Donec vel urna ac lacus consectetur cursus. Donec tempor justo ornare libero eleifend, id ultrices nisi tincidunt. Donec ac orci eget ligula auctor pretium sit amet eu purus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nunc ac luctus elit. Sed consectetur, elit at consequat mollis, justo lectus pellentesque lectus, malesuada congue erat velit eu tortor. Donec ullamcorper nibh a dui convallis venenatis. In a ullamcorper nulla, id porttitor nunc. Praesent elit orci, aliquam vel nunc sed, scelerisque tincidunt ex. Duis consequat dignissim lacus, id porttitor libero fringilla quis. Fusce libero dolor, consectetur id pharetra at, tristique eget sem. Donec et mollis nunc, in aliquet ligula.</p>

  <p>Cras pellentesque imperdiet laoreet. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque ultrices aliquet pretium. Integer auctor sem magna, eget condimentum sapien elementum ac. Nunc finibus feugiat aliquet. Quisque libero ligula, congue sit amet vestibulum at, euismod a elit. Vivamus eget augue et nunc lobortis hendrerit sed ut turpis. Donec et ante commodo, faucibus felis in, viverra libero. Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis euismod magna eget metus tincidunt dapibus. Curabitur malesuada efficitur venenatis. Fusce eu nisi sed purus hendrerit consectetur et ac tellus. Cras placerat dignissim mauris, egestas bibendum eros pulvinar non. Quisque finibus eget elit eu placerat. Mauris diam metus, imperdiet et libero sit amet, venenatis finibus libero. Cras eget laoreet justo.</p>

  <p>Proin sit amet orci nec magna tincidunt vehicula. Praesent mauris elit, ullamcorper eget odio sed, pulvinar luctus tellus. Mauris tempus, magna tempus vulputate efficitur, elit lectus accumsan est, ultricies volutpat nulla ante in sapien. Morbi condimentum erat sit amet mattis ullamcorper. Nullam tincidunt nunc vel leo vulputate porttitor. Donec efficitur hendrerit nunc, non viverra libero scelerisque ac. Ut gravida nec ante vitae facilisis. Pellentesque sagittis urna sit amet egestas vestibulum.</p>

  <p>Duis tempus dui in interdum ullamcorper. Curabitur vulputate laoreet est, dictum condimentum sapien vehicula eget. Pellentesque ac dictum mi. Sed metus arcu, sodales lobortis urna vel, feugiat ullamcorper est. Integer lacinia, lacus ac tristique convallis, nunc purus bibendum arcu, at eleifend enim est non ipsum. Nam iaculis elementum convallis. Nulla tempus odio vel porta ullamcorper. Donec dignissim ut elit vestibulum faucibus.</p>

  <p>Aenean a pulvinar ante. Nunc rutrum volutpat tincidunt. Aenean ultricies sodales mauris eget suscipit. Proin rhoncus ornare lacus in auctor. Duis nec urna sit amet tortor ullamcorper sagittis non nec massa. Nullam dolor sem, laoreet sit amet elit in, iaculis consequat turpis. Morbi semper nulla vel egestas ultrices. Suspendisse id est iaculis, facilisis metus non, accumsan augue. Vestibulum arcu nulla, porta euismod felis et, sollicitudin vehicula ligula. Pellentesque ac dolor ac eros gravida tempus. Etiam sed sem ultrices, tincidunt purus eget, porttitor eros. Vivamus ut tempor sem. Donec interdum efficitur mollis.</p>

  <p>In a laoreet ante. Suspendisse potenti. In sit amet enim elit. In arcu mauris, luctus a urna eget, aliquet accumsan tellus. Maecenas egestas, sem nec commodo tincidunt, metus tortor volutpat libero, eget tristique metus velit sed eros. Fusce bibendum lacus id lectus semper, id volutpat turpis dictum. Vestibulum eu elit eget eros dictum cursus. Mauris consectetur dolor eu ligula condimentum aliquam at id dui. Vestibulum non dolor ante. Morbi a dapibus erat. Nulla placerat mi id neque rhoncus, et semper dolor hendrerit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas quam sem, dapibus non aliquet iaculis, mollis id urna.</p>

  <p>Integer pellentesque enim a justo venenatis sodales. Etiam in nisl ipsum. Vestibulum fringilla dignissim faucibus. Nam pellentesque, mi ac accumsan mattis, elit velit bibendum lacus, id scelerisque ligula sapien id diam. Sed condimentum rutrum metus, in sollicitudin quam ultricies ut. Phasellus at lobortis arcu. Duis auctor, arcu id hendrerit faucibus, odio turpis finibus mi, molestie tempus ex lorem suscipit enim. Nam pretium laoreet ipsum. Donec eu mauris euismod, varius mi id, elementum leo. Integer ultricies nulla massa, in consequat lectus pellentesque ut. Ut eu risus mi. Pellentesque id ligula sodales, maximus lorem at, bibendum velit. Etiam vitae eros vitae quam lacinia egestas. Sed ullamcorper egestas magna, eget suscipit nulla euismod a. Morbi accumsan arcu a vulputate iaculis.</p>

</div>
```